# Email already Exists in ajax call to jsp page by checking database

Tags: html, ajax

in the code its coming like email already exists . but my intention is after entering email if its already exists means it should disappear and should ask for another email id here is my code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
var k=document.getElementById("email").value;
var urls="otr_pass.jsp?email="+k;

 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {
        //document.getElementById("err").style.color="red";
        document.getElementById("err").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",urls,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

```html
 <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email"  onkeyup="loadXMLDoc()" required/> <span id="err"> </span></td>
                   </tr>
```